# 16th century vocabulary - harpsichord

Tags: vocabulary, latin-to-english-translation, idiom

In a 16th century text about musical tuning by Benedetti, the author provides this diagram, which he uses to describe his process of tuning the notes on a harpsichord:

[image: Benedetti's tuning diagram]

In the text, he begins his discussion by writing:

> Sit exempli gratia, hic subscriptus ordo lignorum tangentium seu pinarum...

I am wondering about the interpretation of "lignorum tangentium seu pinarum". To me, the "ligna" seem to be related to the wood of the keys of the instrument, which is somewhat backed up by "tangentium" for the touching aspect (similar to "touches" in French). And the "pina" (pinna?) seem to be the pins/pegs by which the strings are tuned. So a translation like:

> For example, let there be the sequence of keys [notes] or [tuning] pins written here below...

or perhaps even better:

> For example, let there be the keyboard or tuning pin layout written here below...

Any thoughts?

Comment: My first impression, strengthened by the longer passage found at https://edition-open-sources.org/sources/2/14/47.html#transcription , is that _pina_ is used here as a synonym of _lignum tangens,_ both meaning _key._ I might be wrong.I’ll do some research and post an answer when I stand on firmer ground

Comment: That seems quite plausible, "pinnula" is often used in instrument building to refer to the keys / keylevers, e.g. multiple times in these transcripts: http://www.peter-bavington.co.uk/Mersennepaper.pdf (cf. appendix 2). And the use of “seu” would seem to support more the idea of a synonym.